# How to autoresize content of a Borderpane?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a BorderPane and a AnchorPane Layout.

When i'm trying to insert the AnchorPane into a BorderPane, and i maximize or minimize the BorderPane, AnchorPane dont resize itself according to his Parent (BorderPane).

I try to put AnchorPane to the center of BorderPane and i made it autoresizable. But its not working.

```
parent.setCenter(anchorPane);
anchorPane.autoresize();
```

How can i set AnchorPane and its BorderPane Parent, so that by resizing Parent the Child resize itself?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [BorderPaneDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)

> BorderPane honors the minimum, preferred, and maximum sizes of its
>   children. If the child's resizable range prevents it from be resized
>   to fit within its position

Make sure that you dont have a maximum size for your anchor pane.